Use Embedded PDF Type0 FontFile2 with PangoCairo
I'm parsing a PDF file with lopdf and displaying the text with gtk4 and PangoCairo. Up until now I have been using Arial for all text. Basically a proof of concept that I can extract and display text. It looks great!
I am able to extract the text within Tj operations and parse with ToUnicode and cmap information pulled from Tf but I cannot seem to bridge the gap between the embedded Type0 font data (DejaVu in this case) and how to display via Pango and/or PangoFc.
After drilling down into the font object I reach the descendant font information. For example, the dict is:
// <</Type /Font/BaseFont /BAAAAA+DejaVuSans/CIDSystemInfo 18 0 R/CIDToGIDMap /Identity/FontDescriptor 16 0 R/Subtype 
// /CIDFontType2/W [3 [318] 8 [950 780] 11 12 390 13 [500 838 318 361 318 337] 19 28 636 29 [337] 32 33 838 36 
// [684 686 698 770 632 575 775 752] 44 45 295 46 [656 557 863 748 787 603 787 695 635 611 732 684 989 685 611 685 390] 
// 64 [390] 66 [500] 68 [613 635 550 635 615 352] 74 75 635 76 [278] 78 [579 278 974 634 612 635] 85 [411 521 392 634 592 818] 
// 91 92 592 97 [838]]>>

and the descendant font descriptor (16 0 R) is:
// <</Type /FontDescriptor/Ascent 928.22266/CIDSet 9232 0 R/CapHeight 928.22266/Descent -235.83984/Flags 32/
// FontBBox [-1020.5078 -415.03906 1680.6641 1166.5039]/FontFile2 9233 0 R/FontName /BAAAAA+DejaVuSans/ItalicAngle 0/StemV 1>>

The object that FontFile2 points to is an array of bytes. I am assuming this array is a subset of what one would find inside of an actual TTF font file. If I try to parse the content using lopdf it returns an empty Operation vector. So again, I assume this is raw binary data. Comparing against the actual DejaVu TTF file hexdump kinda supports this assumption.
So what do I do now? My naive approach was to use the ttf-parser crate. The Face::parse function returns an OK with a glyph count of 98, but none of the names, glyph names, etc... populate, so I am not sure it actually worked.
let font_desc_id = descendant_dict.get(b"FontDescriptor").unwrap().as_reference().unwrap();
let font_desc_dict = doc.get_object(font_desc_id).unwrap().as_dict().unwrap();
// <</Type /FontDescriptor/Ascent 928.22266/CIDSet 9232 0 R/CapHeight 928.22266/Descent -235.83984/Flags 32/
// FontBBox [-1020.5078 -415.03906 1680.6641 1166.5039]/FontFile2 9233 0 R/FontName /BAAAAA+DejaVuSans/ItalicAngle 0/StemV 1>>
match font_desc_dict.get(b"FontFile2") {
    Ok(o) => {
        let font_file_id = o.as_reference().unwrap();
        let font_file_obj = doc.get_object(font_file_id).unwrap();
        //debug!("Font File Object: {:?}", font_file_obj);
        let font_file_stream = font_file_obj.as_stream().unwrap();
        let font_content = &font_file_stream.content;

        //TODO this is an array of bytes. How do we use it?
        debug!("{:?}", font_content);
        let face = Face::parse(&font_content[..], 0);
        match face {
            Ok(o) => {
                debug!("Glyph Count: {:?}", o.number_of_glyphs());
                for i in 0..o.number_of_glyphs() {
                    match o.glyph_name(GlyphId(i)) {
                        Some(d) => {
                            debug!("{}", d);
                        },
                        None => {
                            debug!("No Glyph Name");
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            },
            Err(_) => {
                error!("Faild to parse font face");
            }
        };
    }
    Err(_) => ()
};

Partial output:
DEBUG - Glyph Count: 98
DEBUG - No Glyph Name
DEBUG - No Glyph Name
DEBUG - No Glyph Name
DEBUG - No Glyph Name
DEBUG - No Glyph Name
DEBUG - No Glyph Name
DEBUG - No Glyph Name
DEBUG - No Glyph Name
DEBUG - No Glyph Name
DEBUG - No Glyph Name
DEBUG - No Glyph Name
DEBUG - No Glyph Name
DEBUG - No Glyph Name

I need help. How do I parse a Type0 FontFile2 and get it into a format that Pango can understand?

As well as being subsetted, the embedded font has likely been stripped to a bare minimum for rendering.  glyph name and encoding tables have likely been removed.
